# Linear Discriminant Analysis for Training and Testing of data sets

Tags: classification, pattern-recognition

I browsed through lots of literature on **Linear Discriminant Analysis** on the web. I can say that, I have understood most of it.

This is what I understood. You take the data, calculate mean of the **data**, **mean per class**, **scatter between classes**, **scatter within a class**. Use this information to project multi-dimensional data onto a single line and hence reduce dimensionality.

However, I don't understand how do I use it for **training and testing of the data sets**.

Also, I know that **Y = X dot W**

Y is projected data
X is original data and
W is the calculated vector used for projection.

So, do I save **W** and use it to project new data?

I hope I am on the right track!